# Sorting strings of different length with digit suffix

Tags: python, string, sorting

I have a a list of lists, based on the first element of each list I want to sort the list. Sample of these indices:

```
  vlan1                    
  usb0                   
  eth1                     
  vlan4                   
  vlan20
```

If they were each the same length as vlanX I would do something like:

```
 table_data = sorted(table_data, key = lambda x: int(x[0][4:]))
```

I'd like to sort them in a manner where vlans come first, and then the rest don't matter. Great if they are sorted but not essential (I don't think there will ever be more than one usb or eth).

```
  vlan1
  vlan4 
  vlan20                    
  usb0                    
  eth1
```

Is this simple to adjust my lambda to do or should I just try and make a function to do it?

I tried this but obviously it leaves the usb and eth in their wrong place untouched, while sorting the vlans.

```
table_data = sorted(table_data, key = lambda x: x = True if "vlan" not in x[0] else int(x[0][4:]))
```

EDIT: that thread does not answer what I want? That would sort the usb and eth elements in between the vlan elements, which is not what I want.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I thought that example answer would sort all the elements in  human readable way, which is not what I want. Does that still make it similar enough to be closed. mine is more like grouping similar elements and then sorting their associated numbers.

Comment: `table_data.sort(key=lambda x:(x[:4]!='vlan', int(x[4:] or 0)))`

Comment: @gnibbler I tried that but it didn't sort all the vlans correctly. It gave me 1, 15, 20, 3 when i tried those numbers.

Comment: @Paul: Your problem is still that you need natural sorting within the `vlan` group.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah is ee what the problem was, does this seem reasonable? `table_data.sort(key=lambda x:(x[0][:4]!='vlan', int(x[0][4:] or 0)))` Just going to test it out with other lists now.

Comment: Given your sample input that looks reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a function to split the names in (prefix, index), and pass it to the `key` parameter.

```
import re
table_data = ["vlan1", "usb0", "eth1", "vlan4", "vlan20"]

def get_key(v):
    prefix, index = re.match(r'([a-z]+)(\d+)', v).groups()
    return prefix, -int(index)

>>> sorted(table_data, key=get_key, reverse=True)
['vlan1', 'vlan4', 'vlan20', 'usb0', 'eth1']
```

You want the order to be descending by prefix and ascending by index, the function is converting the index to negative so the order is right when the list is reversed.

[update]

> No, the OP does not want the order to be descending by prefix. The OP wants 'vlan' to be sorted first, regardless. That happens to fit with descending alphabetic sorting, but not if a 'wlan' key was ever added to the data. – Martijn Pieters

Fair enough.

```
def get_key(v):
    prefix, index = re.match(r'([a-z]+)(\d+)', v).groups()
    if prefix == 'vlan':
        prefix = '~'
    return prefix, -int(index)

>>> table_data = ["vlan1", "usb0", "eth1", "vlan4", "vlan20", "wlan0"]
>>> sorted(table_data, key=get_key, reverse=True)
['vlan1', 'vlan4', 'vlan20', 'wlan0', 'usb0', 'eth1']
```

How about assembling a dict?

```
interfaces = {}
for iface in table_data:
    prefix, index = re.match(r'([a-z]+)(\d+)', iface).groups()
    interfaces.setdefault(prefix, []).append(iface)
for v in interfaces.values():
    v.sort(key=lambda x: int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group(0)))

>>> interfaces
{'eth': ['eth1'],
 'usb': ['usb0'],
 'vlan': ['vlan1', 'vlan4', 'vlan20'],
 'wlan': ['wlan0']}

>>> interface_types = interfaces.keys()
>>> interface_types
['eth', 'vlan', 'wlan', 'usb']

>>> interfaces['vlan']
['vlan1', 'vlan4', 'vlan20']
```

Comment: No, the OP does not want the order to be descending by prefix. The OP wants 'vlan' to be sorted first, regardless. That happens to fit with descending alphabetic sorting, but not if a 'wlan' key was ever added to the data.

Comment: as @MartijnPieters says wlan would be a problem here, and could certainly be in there. But nice answer, I like this tuple sort.

Comment: @PauloScardine  thanks, didn't know about setdefault, very handy.